# Laravel user model conditional eager loading (with)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am working on a hybrid app build with Laravel and Vue.
I have a use case where not all users have certain relations. For example a client can have a *Domain* and Multiple *Business Units*.

Currently i have set it up like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Lab404\Impersonate\Models\Impersonate;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\AsArrayObject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
  use Traits\BaseModelTrait;
  use Traits\ActiveTrait;

  use InteractsWithMedia;
  use Impersonate;
  use HasApiTokens;
  use Notifiable;
  use HasFactory;

  protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
  ];

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar',
  ];

  protected $casts = [
    'settings' => AsArrayObject::class,
    'is_admin' => 'boolean',
  ];

  protected $with = [
    'domain',
    'BusinessUnits'
  ];

  public function scopeAdmin($query)
  {
    return $query->where('is_admin', true);
  }

  public function scopeEmployee($query)
  {
    return $query->whereNull('domain_id');
  }

  public function scopeClient($query)
  {
    return $query->whereNotNull('domain_id');
  }

  public function BusinessUnits()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(BusinessUnit::class, 'users_business_units_pivot');
  }

  public function Domain()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Domain::class);
  }
}
```

The "problem" with this approach is that for every request 2 queries are executed for each user. I want the relations eager loaded only if the "domain_id" is not null (scopeClient).
For normal "models" i can select per page what models should be loaded etc., but for the authenticated user this is not really possible as i know.

I think i am looking for something like this:

```php
  protected $with = [
    (!$this->domain_id) ? 'domain' : null,
    (!$this->domain_id) ? 'BusinessUnits' : null
  ];
```

This currently generates an error: "Constant expression contains invalid operations."

Any advice and or ideas to tackle this would be appreciated!

Comment: so you want to add to the User model, the `domain_id`? please post the output you are having, and the desired one

Comment: No the user already has a domain_id. For the authenticated users where the `domain_id` is not null, i want the the Domain relation eager loaded.

Comment: what you are asking is very confusing, the answer does what you are asking, so please, clarify what you want, giving an example of input/output of what you are doing, what you want and what you are getting

Comment: I mean, just preload `domain`, if `domain_id` it will eager loaded to an empty collection...

Comment: I don't want the query executed if i already know he doesn't have a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using events:

```
// this code should be inside your model
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::retrieved(function($model){
        if($model->domain_id !== null)
        {
             $model->load('domain', 'BusinessUnits');
        }
    });
}
```

and obviously, you have to remove those relations from `$with`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! You are a true hero, thank you!

Comment: @RobertFridzema glad to see it helped, sorry fo the comments, but I like to deeply understand the problem before giving a possible answer (also, in case you need it, you can find here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events all the possible events that you can use in the `boot` function)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the user that has domains, use `whereHas()`

```
$users = User::whereHas('Domain')->with(['Domain', 'BusinessUnits'])->get();
```

it will lauch 3 queries, one for the users, one for the domains and one for the business units.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method i use for every other model than the user. I want the relations conditionally loaded for the Authenticated user, preferable in the User model.

Comment: @RobertFridzema then add it to your authentification middleware to preload the domain when a user is authentified.

Comment: Seems not the right place to do it. Are you referring to the "Authenticate" middleware class? Can't find a way to modify the authenticated user (query) here either.

Comment: @RobertFridzema You make a new middleware that entends the one in the vendor, put it in place of the vendor one in kernel.php and override the handle method. now in the handle method, do the same code present in the vendor one and add your code.